# Making folder simulation in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a program/method to use with actionscript-3 in order to make a virtual folder hierarchy that contains my images and sounds and traverse it at runtime in order to select what to load on the SWF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the best way would be to have XML file that defines your image paths.